# Convex sets of real numbers

Tags: convex-analysis, real-numbers

Suppose I start with a convex set of real numbers and I take the square of each number in the set? Is the resulting set of real numbers itself convex?

Comment: It might help to note that a convex set of real numbers is just an interval.

Comment: And the image of an interval under any continuous mapping is also an interval.

Answer (score 4):

A convex set of real numbers is an interval.  When you square each point in an interval, you get another interval, so yes.